# Get data in class

Tags: c#, class

I have class student :

```
public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public Student()
        {
        }
        public List<Student> getData()
        {
            List<Student> st = new List<Student> 
            {
                new Student{Name="Pham Nguyen",Age = "22"},
                new Student{Name="Phi Diep",Age = "22"},
                new Student{Name="Khang Tran",Age = "28"},
                new Student{Name="Trong Khoa",Age = "28"},
                new Student{Name="Quan Huy",Age = "28"},
                new Student{Name="Huy Chau",Age = "28"},
                new Student{Name="Hien Nguyen",Age = "28"},
                new Student{Name="Minh Sang",Age = "28"},
            };
            return st;
        }        
    }
```

How can I take data in this class? ( I mean - example : I want take Name="Minh Sang",Age = "28" to show).

sorry about this question. but i don't know where to find it.

thanks all

Comment: Why don't you start with learning basics, not just copy-pasting the samples you don't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 1:**
Add these methods to your class:

```
public Student getStudent(int age, string name)
{
    return this.getData().Find(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Age) == age && s.Name.Equals(name));
}

public Student getByIndex(int index)
{
    Student s = null;
    // maxIndex will be: 7
    // your array goes from 0 to 7
    int maxIndex = this.getData().Count() - 1;
    // If your index does not exceed the elements of the array:
    if (index <= maxIndex)
        s  = this.getData()[index];
    return s;
}
```

- I convert the age to `int` if you need to evaluate in future `>` or `<`.

**EDIT 2:**
Then invoke the methods like this:

```
    Student st = new Student();
    // s1 and s2 will return null if no result found.
    Student s1 = st.getStudent(28, "Minh Sang");
    Student s2 = st.getByIndex(7);

    if (s1 != null)
        Console.WriteLine(s1.Age);
        Console.WriteLine(s1.Name);
    if (s2 != null)
        Console.WriteLine(s2.Age);
        Console.WriteLine(s2.Name);
```

Comment: can i find that data just know number of list ( i mean this list have number form 0 to 7 - the data Name="Huy Chau",Age = "28" have number 5). have i add "public string Number { get; set; }" in my class ?

Comment: If you want to put an EXTRA identifier (number) for your users in list, then you can do a search with "Find" as my example. However, the list of users has indexes inside like: user at position 0, at position 1, etc. and also you can do a kind of "search"

Comment: oh. so the list of users has indexes inside. how can i search with that position ?

Comment: one more question: have you do it at another way? (if i have a big class and i don't want to "GetData" again)

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq:

```
Student st = new Student();

var getStudent = from a in st.getData()
                      where a.Age == "28" & a.Name == "Minh Sang"
                      select a;

MessageBox.Show(getStudent.First().Age);
MessageBox.Show(getStudent.First().Name);
```

Comment: +1. You should have gone all the way and create and populate controls in the same LINQ statement... :)

Comment: can i find that data just know number of list ( i mean this list have number form 0 to 7 - the data Name="Huy Chau",Age = "28" have number 5). have i add "public string Number { get; set; }" in my class ?

Comment: yes you can just add public string Number { get; set; }  and  on new Student{StudentNumber="1",Name="Minh Sang",Age = "28"}

Answer (score 0):

Look at the List.Find Method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx

Next try implementing a new method:

```
public Student GetStudent(string name, int age)
```

Answer (score 0):

Call getData() to get a list of the students.

Iterate through the list with a foreach loop.

Inside the loop, print out the name and age of the Student.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [DebuggerDisplay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx) attribute to show it in debugger?

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Name = {name}, Age={age}")]
public class Student {....}
```

So when you hover over an item of type Student it will be shown the way you want...